# mimic message layout of android to own application

Tags: android, layout, message

I am new to android and i am building sms application that will send the messages and i want to memik the layout of android's send message layout.

I have tried but not suceeded.if there is a layout you can refer?.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "12125551212");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Intent will take it to the device's default SMS activity and handle it for you... you don't have to do anything more